# don't want to wait for socket.accept() each loop iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, esp8266, micropython

I'm using the line "conn, addr = httpSocket.accept()", but I don't want to wait for it every iteration of my loop because there won't always be someone trying to connect. Is there a way to check if anyone is trying to connect, and move on if there isn't?

I have looked at using asyncio (I can't use threads because this is micropython on an esp8266, and threading is not supported) but my line is not awaitable.

```py
with open('page.html', 'r') as file:
    html = file.read()

while True:
    conn, addr = httpSocket.accept()
    print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
    conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
    conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
    conn.sendall(html)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: *move on if there isn't* - do you want to proceed with the logic going right after the loop?

Comment: micropython is a bit special, I'd checkout their [`uselect` module](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/uselect.html) as it should allow you to do as @Amit suggests

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Ideally I would like to ask "is someone trying to connect?" and have an "if yes" and an "if no" to decide what to do

Answer (score 1):

If threads isn't an option you can always use the `select` module.
With select you basically split your sockets into 3 categories:

1. Sockets that you want to read data from them (including new connections).
2. Sockets that you want to send them data.
3. Exceptional sockets ( usually for error checking).

And with each iteration select returns to you lists of sockets by these categories, so you know how to handle each one instead of waiting for a new connection each time.

You can see an example here:
https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/